# What Ember Add-on do I need for this situation?

Tags: javascript, css, ember.js, color-picker

I am wondering if there is an ember add-on that I can implement to do the following.

```
|-----------------------------------------------v----|
green                 yellow                      red
```

Color gradient bar of green > yellow > red and the v represents a value that lands there.  Also where green, yellow, red start is based on values, so green could be 0-20 and yellow 21-40 and red 41+

I don't know what something like this would be called, but if anyone can let me know and help point me in the right direction, I would be much obliged.

Comment: You're looking for two `<div>`s with their backgrounds set to linear gradients, plus some basic math. ember.js doesn't really enter the picture.

Comment: Can you show me an example on like jsfiddle or something of how that works? Never done this before

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/fj4wug4v/

Comment: so far I haven't see a Ember add-on but you can use a J-query plug in and then implement it using ember.... we have use this http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/demo.html   check that out.. works well..... by the way is call range slider..

Comment: Did you look at `<input type="color">`? Or do you really want a slider? If it's a slider, all you need is a regular slider (`<input type="range">`) with some styling of the background using a gradient, If you want something that's Ember-ready, try googling for "ember color picker". BTW, it's recommended to use more descriptive titles, rather than "for this situation", say "color slider" or something. That way people browsing lists of questions will find it easier to know what the question's about.

Comment: @ChrisG Why two divs?

Comment: @torazaburo You're right, one is enough.

Comment: Don't want to be a slider per say since the user shouldn't be able to interact with it. Should work like a data visualization component.

Comment: @Chris G The way your fiddle works is exactly what I wanted, thank you so much! For future reference, what is something like this called? Color bar or something?

Comment: I'm no native speaker but I guess it's a "gauge".

Comment: Awesome, thanks again :)

Comment: @ChrisG Can you please post your findings as an answer?  This way, you can gain reputation for the answer, and, the question will no longer appear unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
var min = 0;
var max = 60;

function set(x) {
  var left = (x - min) / (max - min) * 100;
 document.getElementById("V").style.left = left + "%";
}

set(50);
```

```css
#gauge {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green 0%, yellow 50%, red 100%);
  height: 2em;
  position: relative
}

#V {
  width: 0;
  height: 2.4em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.2em
}
```

```html
<div id="gauge">
  <div id="V"></div>
</div>
```